# ionic ios app with in-app purchase - how to test in-app consumable product before first submission of the app and product

Tags: ios, ionic3, in-app-purchase, app-store, ionic-native

Building an ionic 3 app and want to add in-app purchases for iOS. But can't seem to be able to test the in-app purchase products.

I integrated with both Native in app purchase plugins from the [Ionic Native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/) documentation website
[In App Purchase](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-purchase/) and [In App Purchase 2](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-purchase-2/) i am not able to test any of the products. i always get the error that the **"Unknown product identifier"**. 
(**NOTE:** this works ok with Google Play in-app purchases)

Important : this is pre any submission of the app with in-app purchases to the App Store (however the app has been approved before and is published in the App Store).
I already have an in-app purchase product created in App Store Connect that is "cleared for sale" and "ready for submission".

also - i have checked the following:

1. Paid Applications contract in iTunes is signed
2. in-app purchase capability in Xcode is turned on (i run `ionic cordova prepare ios` and opened the workspace in Xcode)
3. App ID in the Identifiers section of developer.apple.com page exists and has In-App Purchase Enabled for both Dev and Distribution
4. created Sandbox user for testing

All the above being considered i tried building both in Debug and Release mode - with iOS App Development profile and App Store or Ad Hoc distribution profiles and deployed to a trusted device and always get that same error when i try to purchase the product **"Unknown product identifier"**.

Is there something i am missing - is there something i need to do for the build, or set-up on the profiles. Or does it have to do with the in-app purchase product not being approved yet (although i can't submit the product without submitting a new build with in-app purchases and the new build is not good because i can't test the product - kind of the egg and the chicken problem).

Any help and/or pointers would be appreciated, as i ran out of ideas.

Comment: From my experience building this out using Xamarin I had to submit my iOS app to testflight(https://developer.apple.com/testflight/). The product does need to exist but does not need to be approved.